# rdlc could not be found in published project by oneClick

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis, rdlc, reportviewer

I have programed an application in visual studio and ithas reports of report Viewer(rdlc)it workes fine on development machine, but when I deploy it on server (IIS 6) ,the program won't run and fails, what it says : downloading report.rdlc did not succeed .The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.. the file exist in the "application files" folder in published application.

what I have done is that:
1-in the report file the build action is "Content" and it always copy
2-in the server I add a Mapping for the rdls extention to aspnet.isapi.dll location
3- in the application files of publishing it is set to "Include(Auto)"
what else can I do to run the application with rdlc?

Answer (score 1):

These are what I have done to solve the problem:

1. in Publish page of project properties, in the prerequisites , I checked the Microsoft Visual studio 2010 Report Viewer
2. in the Application Files page of project properties, I changed the publish Status to "Include" of the following files

   ```
    a) Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
    b) Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll
    c) Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
    d) Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForm.dll
   ```
3. I checked the value of "Use .deploy file extenstion" in following Path
   Properties of Project => Publish => Options => Deployment

These changes solved my Problem.